# SIMBL plugin with a Sandboxed app

Tags: plugins, osx-lion, sandbox, textedit, simbl

I have created a SIMBL plugin for TextEdit in Lion however I am unable to send an NSDistributedNotification with a userInfo object as the Sandbox stops the Notification from being posted.

I get the following message:
TextEdit: *** attempt to post distributed notification thwarted by sandboxing.

I believe it has something to do with the following entitlement;
com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events

How do I implement this in my plugin? Or do I need to alter the entitlements for TextEdit in order to send notifications?

Answer (score 0):

distributed notifications no longer allow you to specify a userInfo payload under sandboxing.  the apple events entitlement doesn't help you with distributed notifications as they are completely different things. Additionally the entitlements are on the application and modifying them will invalidate the app's code signature which will also prevent the application from running, so entitlements aren't the way to go.